# Request for references of random matrices

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-matrices

I need some good books aimed as a detailed and gentle introduction to random matrices, containing good discussion and derivation of Marchenko–Pastur distribution. Also, I request some other references on the application side that discuss the  applications of random matrices  to  fields like finance, random polynomials and physics. I would be highly obliged for any recommendations .

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in doing research in this field, you will want to learn of major applications, and for that purpose I could recommend the various chapters of [The Oxford Handbook of Random Matrix Theory.](https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/43656) The book is expensive, but many of the chapters are on arXiv. In particular, part III includes a great number of applications.

Here is [a list](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=oxford+handbook+random&searchtype=comments&source=header) of 17 chapters from the Handbook on arXiv, including chapters on [financial applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1205) and on [physics applications.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1432)